# How do I fix this strange Windows 7 menu behavior?

Tags: windows-7

On my Windows 7 64bit Pro install, for no apparent reasons, all menus suddenly align with their right side lined up with the menu item, rather than the traditional left side.  This happens regardless of what may be crowding the screen or menus.  If I maximize the app, all the first sets of menu items will open with their menu slammed against the left side of the screen.

Anyone have any idea what this might be or how I can revert to default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any Arabic or Right to Left language packs installed?

Go to `Control Panel` > `Region and Languages` and just take a look round to make sure all of them are set correctly for you.

Comment: I remember it having something to do with TabletPC options, for people using a tablet PC with stylus.

Comment: paradroid is correct, to get the "normal" behavior, do this: Start -> Control Panel -> Tablet PC Settings -> Other (tab) -> click "Left-handed"